# Mysql/InnoDB or Postgresql?

Tags: database

I have to use a dbms that support transactions. 
So I thought mysql + innodb or postgresql.

Why Mysql+innodb is better ?

Why Postgresql is better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is too general of a term.  Better in what area or areas?  Take a look at [this unbiased^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Houtdated comparison](http://www-css.fnal.gov/dsg/external/freeware/pgsql-vs-mysql.html).  Or perhaps [this one](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL).  Then choose which one is better based on your criteria.

Comment: Nonsense, the internet *NEVER* lies.  LOL

Comment: let's see: section *Platforms*: PostgreSQL "Lacks binary distribution for all the supported plataforms," whereas MySQL has "binary distribution for most of the supported plataforms."  Let's say "PostgreSQL has binary distributions for most of the supported platforms" and "MySQL lacks binary distribution for all the supported plataforms" and see if it sounds different.